# Создание и вывод файла пользователю

Tags: javascript

На клиенте формирую файл и выдаю его пользователю следующим способом:

```
function createAndUploadFile (name, type, body)
{
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new window.Blob([body], { type: type }));
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
};
```

Всё работает нормально, но IE выдаёт ошибку Access Denied. 
Как в этом браузере можно выгрузить файл без участия сервера?